# How to add gradient effect in selected image object from HTML canvas using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have html canvas where i dropped image on it i want to apply linear gradient effect on image. My scenario is that user can select some portion of image on canvas by mouse and he can select color from color picker. I want to apply effect on selected portion only.

[image: please see selected image portion]

Comment: i have used fabric js for image filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a job for [createRadialGradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createRadialGradient):

```js
var mouse = {
  down: false,
  x1: null,
  y1: null,
  x2: null,
  y1: null
};
var grad = 'transparent';
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = init;
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/D%C3%BClmen%2C_Kirchspiel%2C_B%C3%B6rnste%2C_Feld_--_2017_--_3171.jpg/500px-D%C3%BClmen%2C_Kirchspiel%2C_B%C3%B6rnste%2C_Feld_--_2017_--_3171.jpg";


function updateGrad() {
  var cx = mouse.x1;
  var cy = mouse.y1;
  var dist = Math.hypot(mouse.x1-mouse.x2, mouse.y1-mouse.y2);
    
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(cx, cy, 0, cx, cy, dist);
  
  grad.addColorStop(1, 'black');
  grad.addColorStop(0, 'transparent');
}

function draw() {
  // draw the image
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
  // draw the gradient
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  // draw the line?
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(mouse.x1 - 4, mouse.y1 - 4, 8, 8);
  ctx.moveTo(mouse.x1, mouse.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(mouse.x2, mouse.y2);
  ctx.rect(mouse.x2 - 4, mouse.y2 - 4, 8, 8);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function init() {
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  canvas.onmousedown = mousedown;
  document.onmousemove = mousemove;
  document.onmouseup = mouseup;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
  draw();
}

function mousedown(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouse.down = true;
  mouse.x1 = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  mouse.y1 = evt.clientY - rect.top;
}

function mousemove(evt) {
  if(!mouse.down) return;
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouse.x2 = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  mouse.y2 = evt.clientY - rect.top;
  updateGrad();
  draw();
}

function mouseup(evt) {
  mouse.down = false;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: how to remove stroke() and keep gradient as it is at the time of save canvas

Comment: @PavanHukerikar create an other drawing function, with everything from the current `draw` until that line: `// draw the line?`